# How to access a Postgres db from Excel Mac?

Tags: excel, macos, postgresql, odbc

I need to create a really simple table in Excel with data from a Postgres db in localhost.

I've managed to do it with [OpenLink PostgreSQL Lite Driver](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-postgres-st/) but doesn't look friendly or manageable. I used to use ODBC on Windows, but I'm not sure on OS X. I need it to be open source.

Comment: ODBC is the pretty much the same on OS X as on Windows. The closed-source OpenLink driver you used here came from my employer... What "doesn't look friendly or manageable"? Why do you now require an open source driver?

Answer (score 0):

The official Microsoft method for connecting Excel For Mac to a database is to use one of a few supported drivers, none of which are open source:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ODBC-drivers-that-are-compatible-with-Excel-for-Mac-9FA6BC7F-D19E-4F7F-9BE4-92E85C77D712

Personally, I've used the Actual Technologies driver with Excel For Mac 2011 and it worked, but I had problems with it with the 2016 version of Excel. I was using Postgres as well.

Instead I decided to write the data from the DB out to a csv, and then connect to the csv from Excel. That way I don't have to deal with the database connection, but it's not ideal.

Comment: That link seems to have contrary information since the release of Office 2019:
"The instructions below apply to Excel 2019 and Microsoft 365 for Mac.
These versions of Excel do provide an ODBC driver for connecting to SQL Server Databases." *Note* how it says drivers are included starting with Excel 2019.

However, there don't seem to be actual instructions on how to do it using the built in drivers.